# Ctrl+c is not working as expected in Install4j console mode

Tags: console, runtime, install4j, ctrl

I am developing console mode installer for CentOS platform and facing issues while exiting script with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

I have use following code in console handler.

```
console.println(string1);
console.waitforEnter();
console.println(string2);
```

It prints string1 and next option is waitForEnter. If I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at this point, it prints string2 and then it closes the installer.

The expected behaviour should be closing installer immediately.

Same behaviour is seen while `console.readLine()` as well.

```
int selected=0;
console.println("\033[1;33mInstallation options:\n\n[S] Type 1 Installation\n[D] Type 2 Installation\n");

int opt=0;
while(opt==0)
{

console.println("\033[1;34mTo continue type selection \033[1;33mS \033[1;34mor \033[1;33mD \033[1;34m and hit [Enter] \033[0m");
String choiceS=console.readLine().trim();
console.println(choiceS);
if(choiceS.equals("S"))
{
    selected=0;
    opt=1;
    
}
if(choiceS.equals("D"))
{
    selected=1;
    opt=1;

}
continue;
}
```

It is happening due to while loop.
Please suggest changes for the same.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with Ubuntu. Does it print an exception? If yes, there may be a fix for that in the upcoming 8.0.9 release. That fix is related to CTRL-D (EOF), not to CTRL-C (SIGINT), but maybe there is a connection.

Comment: Nope it is not printing any exception.It closes the installer but first prints the string two as enter is pressed and then installer gets closed. Is it because of the code execution in cancellation event listener or something like that means if that code is taking time to execute hence it prints next line and then closes installer

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com, I have a build that I would like you to test.

Comment: @IngoKegel I have edited the question and have added one code the issue s happening due to while loop please suggest me how to achieve the ctrl+c behaviour with this code.

Comment: It does not depend on the specific code but on the way the JVM shuts down when it receives a SIGINT. I have offered you to contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build with a related change.

Comment: @IngoKegel i have mailed support@ej-technolgies.com regarding same please check.

Comment: @IngoKegel Hi Ingo,
Regarding same issue if we try with ctrl+d it is working fine till installation actions screen but ctrl+d is not working.
Vice versa ctrl+c is working after installation action screen but not working for initial screens.
Any take on this issue?